# Remove automatically Azure Staging Services

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I would like to use Azure Automation to delete all the staging deployments in my cloud services. I would like to run a Powershell script once a day to do so.

Is there any predefined script out there to do so? Any examples?

Comment: was my answer helpful or are you still having the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following Powershell cmdlet can be used to delete deployment slots on a website.You can either loop thru the list of deployment slots or do one by one.

```
Remove-AzureWebsite -Name webappslotstest -Slot staging
```

There's three ways to do this;

- Running this on a VM or a client machine
- Running this as a Webjob in the webapp as powershell script (I'd go with this one)
- Azure Automation as you've asked. You can use a Runbook for this, [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/scripts/) you can find more info on runbooks and sample scripts.

Hope this helps